# How can I seal off exterior hole?

Tags: exterior

I have an A/C line (left) which has been chewed through by mice.

[image]

They are now enjoying the comfort of my attic. I've temporarily put steel wool in the hole, but they have evolved and pulled it out. The hole itself is about 2". The temperatures right now are around 25℉ high, so I worry that mortar will freeze. How else can I seal this hole off?

Comment: I’d pack the steel wool very tight and apply fresh caulk/sealant.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the nose of a tube of 100% silicone calk and pump it full.  They don't like it.

Comment: How would you recommend forming the caulk so that it doesn't just spill out?

Comment: Try it. You'll like it.

Comment: Silicone caulk is fairly self-supporting. You can tool it out and expect it to stay put.

Answer (score 1):

Dow has a Pest Block version of GreatStuff foam now.   I would use that to anchor the steel wool.

http://greatstuff.dow.com/product/pestblock.htm

Answer (score 0):

## Warning: Steel wool is dangerous in this situation!

Use Stucco Netting instead.  It may cost more but could save your life.  Thermostats, whether line voltage or low voltage, have enough power behind their signal to ignite steel wool.  If there's a wire in the hole, don't use steel wool.

I just keep stucco netting at the house along with a can of Pest Block Great Stuff as mentioned by @DaveM.  Another bonus...  it doesn't rust when it rains 30 miles down the road!